# Distortion when loading a picture in ios using opencv

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, opencv, image-processing

The first question I want to ask is:
when I link opencv to my iOS project like this:

[image]

There is distortion when loading the picture to the App:

[image]

and the oringal picture is:

[image]

You see the difference here? Why it happened? And is there any ways to avoid it?

And another question is:
Is there any image processing books/tutorials/websites in opencv using Mat style codes? I read an image processing book using IplImage style codes, so you see my way to do image processing in iOS is first load a IplImage picture and convert it to Mat and finally convert it to UIImage and show it to the view. But Mat is newer than IplImage, anything recommend for me?
Thank you very much!

Comment: A couple of things, you can directly load images as `cv::Mat`, use `cv::Mat img = cv::imread(filename)`, doc [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread). For your problem, opencv loads by default images in BGR so probably you have to change the colorspace to RGB with [`cvtColor`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=cvtcolor#cvtcolor) and the flag `CV_BGR2RGB`

Comment: Thank you, that works for me.